# Sorting rows with different names

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am working with an existing Excel spreadsheet that incorporates child and parent names. (line inserted to separate family) They are not always the same name. How can I maintain the integrity of the child and parent when I need to alpha sort the columns?  (example:  Row 1 is child's name with data spread and Row 2 is parent's name with data spread (names not always matching for an alpha sort).

If I need to reformat spreadsheet I can but I don't know how to set it up.

Comment: Can you please show us an example of your current data setup?

Answer (score 0):

Add a column that will code for family and use that in your alpha sort to keep family rows together.

Say your data is laid out something like this.

[image: example data]

Add the column that will hold the family identifier. By way of example, I inserted a new column `A`.

Cell `A2` contains the formula `A2`, the value of which will be the family name identifier for the first family grouping.

The formula in cell `A3` continues the family name down, taking into account the blank lines that separate family groups. This formula is copied down to the bottom of the data, including the blank line below the last row of data.

```
  =IF(AND(B2="",ISTEXT(B3)),B3,A2)
```

[image: data with family sort column]

The next step is to convert the formulas in column `A` to values by selecting the column `A` range and Special Pasting it in place as Values. After that, you can alpha sort on column A.

This will produce an ordering on the name in the first row of a family group. To sort by the (or a) parent name in the case where the first row has a child (last) name different from the parent requires information about which rows are parent names and which are child names. Need more information on what your data looks like in order to accommodate that.